# IIS can't load Oracle.Web assembly (for ASP.NET membership provider)

Tags: iis, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to configure an IIS web site to use an Oracle database for ASP.NET  membership, but I can't get it to work. IIS doesn't seem to be able to load the assembly containing the Oracle membership provider.

That's what I have so far:

- An Oracle 10g database online and with all the tables for ASP.NET membership created.
- Windows 2008 R2 Standard with the
  web server role installed, including
  support for ASP.NET.
- *Oracle 11g
  Release 2 ODAC 11.2.0.1.2* installed.
  The installed components are: Oracle
  data provider for .NET, Oracle
  providers for ASP.NET, Oracle
  instant client.
- The default web site
  on IIS (I am using that for testing)
  has the following `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
                <membership defaultProvider="OracleMembershipProvider">
                <providers>
                    <remove name="SqlMembershipProvider" />
                    <add name="OracleMembershipProvider" 
type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"
connectionStringName="OracleServer" />
                </providers>
            </membership>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

(Additional attributes on the "add" element omitted for brevity. Also, the connection string is defined for the whole server.)

- The Oracle.Web.dll file is on the GAC. That's the relevant part of the `C:\Windows\Assembly` folder:

[image: Oracle.Web, 2.112.1.2, no culture, 89b483f429c47342, x86]

- The web site application pool is configured for .NET 2.0, and has 32-bit applications enabled.
- I have allowed untrusted providers in the IIS' `administration.config` file (just for the sake of testing, I'll explicitly add the assembly to the trusted providers list later).

With all of this setup in place, when I click on the ".NET Users" icon on the IIS manager, I get a warning about the provider having too much privileges, and when I accept I get the following message:

> There was an error while performing
>   this operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.1.2,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

So, what am I missing? How can I get the Oracle membership provider to work?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** It seems that the problem is not with IIS itself, but with the IIS administrator only. When using the web site configuration tool provided by Visual Studio, everything works fine.

Comment: Does it work if you put that dll into the website's bin folder?